# Databasestructure Relations

Tags: mysql, database-design

Im just creating the Tablestructure for a small Messagesystem in our Intranet.
For the main part I thougt I would use this 2 Tables

```
        1)         2)
Name:   Msg        Msg Content

Fields: id         id 
        to         from
        msg        timestamp
        read       text
                   title
```

msg ist the id of the seccond Table.
I would use 2 Tables, becouse one message can go to mre than one recipient.

Is that way ok? what can I do better?

There should be also the Option to make a Group msg. The Problem with that is n:m. Every Body can have multiple Groups and ofcourse also every Group can have more than one recipeint. There would be a third table ("groups") with id and Name field, but in what table do I put the members in the Group table or the user table?

Hope you have some suggestions. Thanks in advance
js

Comment: for the message you're looking for a one to many relationship, for the groups it's a many to many relationship. See here, hope this help : http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561  . So you have to create another table users_groups wich reference user id and associated group id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is mostly fine for a simple implementation, but be careful with your `Foreign Key` names. "msg" in Msg should be called MsgContentId or something similar if it is the ID pointing to the second table. For a n:m relationship you will just need foreign keys pointing both ways. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you both! I found something bevor in the direction with the additonal table, but didnt understand it. BUt if it means in the table i have datasets like: user1 - group1; user1 - group2; user2 - group1; than i got it know :)